# Monitor for Outlook Folder Rename/Add/Delete with Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a c# outlook add-in and I would like to monitor for folder rename/changes.

After some searching, it looks like I need to monitor for the even, `FoldersEvents_FolderChangeEventHandler`

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  // monitor for folder changes
  var folders = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().Folders;
  folders.FolderChange += Folders_FolderChange;
}

...
private void Folders_FolderChange(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
  //
}
```

But the code is not called when I rename any folders, (or I move them and so on).

So, how can I monitor for changes in any of the folders?

I would like to monitor, `Rename`, `Delete` and `Add`, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up an event sink on a local variable (folders) that gets released by the GC next time it runs. Make it a global (class) member.